# Regular expression for at least 10 characters

Tags: regex

I need a regular expression which checks that a string is at least 10 characters long. It does not matter what those character are.

Thanks

Comment: This sounds like a problem the length() method is designed to solve.

Comment: do spaces and tabs count as characters?

Comment: When you say it does not matter what those characters are, what about whitespace characters?  .{10} will match exactly 10 characters, but will also match "foo bar xx"

Comment: ... and Robert raises a very valid point

Comment: There are some tools which have a validation parameter that can only take in a regex (because the tools are not being accessed via source code).

Comment: @zee please accept an answer or clarify your question further

Comment: How many characters is `ç̃` supposed to count as? What about `ç̃` or `ç̃` or `ç̃̃`? How about `ＷＩＤＥ` or `eﬃcient` or `Henry Ⅷ`? And how about `⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠!⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠`?  I think you’ll find that none of those are what you think they are.

Comment: @Robert: Except in Java, where `String.length()` can lie to you.

Answer (score 36):

You can use:

```
.{10,}
```

Since `.` does not match a newline by default you'll have to use a suitable modifier( if supported by your regex engine) to make `.` match even the newline. Example in Perl you can use the `s` modifier.

Alternatively you can use `[\s\S]` or `[\d\D]` or `[\w\W]` in place of `.`

Answer (score 8):

This will match a string of any 10 characters, including newlines:

```
[\s\S]{10,}
```

(In general, `.` does not match newlines.)

Comment: why use `[\s\S]` instead of `.`

Comment: @Keng: As robert states, `.` won't match newlines.

Comment: @Brian but a lot of platforms don't use `\n` for newlines, they use `\r\n` so that would count as two but only actually be one right?

Comment: `\r\n` is two characters: a carriage return, and a newline. Welcome to the wonderful world of varying text formats.

Comment: @Tim: Most reasonable text-processing finds a way to pretend that legacy CRLFs are just logical newlines.

Comment: The original question asks for string length.  Any manipulation done by I/O libraries when reading in that string is irrelevant.

Answer (score 4):

Does the language you're using not have a string length function (or a library with such a function)? Is it very difficult to implement your own? This seems overkill for regex, but you could just use something like `.{10,}` if you really wanted to. In langauges that have length functions, it might look something like `if (str.length()>10) lenGeq10=true` or `if (length(str) > 10) lenGeq10=true`, etc...  and if whitespace is a concernt, many libraries also have `trim`ing functions to strip whitespace, example: `if (length(trim(str)) > 10) lenGeq10=true...`

Answer (score 0):

A C# solution to see if the string matters as defined by your parameters..

```
string myString = "Hey it's my string!";
bool ItMatters;

ItMatters = myString.Length >= 10;
```

Answer (score -1):

`\S{10,}`

---

disregard below:

extra characters in order to post.

Comment: And if the string contains spaces?

Comment: @Tim Pietzcker that's what I'm waiting on the answer to.

Comment: If your answer needs extra characters in order to post then it is incomplete.

Comment: @MilesRout :no, if you want flowery exposition to decorate a simple code sample, you're on the wrong site.